# not declare in scope when compiled g++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, scope, scope-resolution

This is my A.h file

```
class A
{
public:
    void menuChoice();
void displaystartingMenu(); //EDIT
};
```

This is my A.cpp file

```
#include "A.h"

void displaystartingMenu()
{


    cout<<"Please enter your choice:";


}
void A::menuChoice()
{
    displaystartingMenu();
    cout<<"Hello"<<endl;

}
int main()
{ 
   A a;
   a.menuChoice();

}
```

i tried to put

```
void menuChoice();
```

on the top of my cpp file but it still won't compile . it gives me error

> In function ‘int main()’: A.cpp:112:13: error: ‘menuChoice’ was not declared in this scope   menuChoice();

How do I compile : g++ A.cpp A.h

By right I don't need to even declare the function of top of the cpp because I have already declare it in my header file and I have included in my .cpp. What went wrong here?

**EDIT:**

Error :

```
 In function `A::menuChoice()':
A.cpp:(.text+0x229): undefined reference to `A::displaystartingMenu()'
```

Comment: You meant `A a; a.menuChoice();` ?

Comment: You need an instance of `A` before you can call functions in `A`. That's how classes work. If you don't want that then don't use a class.

Comment: but what if i have another method() already declared public in the class to be place inside menuchoice(); , do i have to make an instance of A in menuchoice(); as well?  if method() is just a cout @immibis

Comment: @user2601570 No. Inside a member function, there's a "current instance" of the class, and you can access functions and variables of that instance by default.

Comment: yup but it says undefined reference when i tried to access @immibis

Comment: @user2601570 That probably means you didn't define it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: Make an `A` instance and call that instance's `menuChoice` method:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
        void menuChoice();
};

void A::menuChoice() {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
        A a;
        a.menuChoice();
        return 0;
}
```

Option 2: Make `menuChoice` a static method and call it as `A::menuChoice`:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
        static void menuChoice();
};

void A::menuChoice() {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
        A::menuChoice();
        return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit**: Addressing the new problem, when you tried to define `A::displaystartingMenu` you wrote:

```
void displaystartingMenu() {
    // ...
}
```

It must be defined like this:

```
void A::displaystartingMenu() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: but what if i have another method(); to be place inside menuchoice(); , i have to do the same in menuchoice(); as well?

Comment: @user2601570, `menuChoice` is a method, you cannot place another method inside of it. You can have a separate method which you call from `menuChoice`, is that what you mean?

Comment: nope if i have a method already declared in the class , then i call it inside menuchoice(); it doesn't work , it says undefined reference

Comment: @user2601570, Then extend your question with this new problem, I can't guess what you did wrong

Comment: i accept yr answer and extend my question because the original question i post have an underlying problem .pls check my edits ! thanks

Answer (score 3):

menuChoice is a non static member function of class A. In order to call it you need to instantiate an object A, as follows

```
int main()
{
  A a;
  a.menuChoice();

  return 0;
}
```